# Rename files based on JSON content

Tags: awk, scripting, rename, json

I have two sets of files:

```
file1.txt     file1.json 
file2.txt     file2.json    
file3.txt     file3.json  
...
fileN.txt     fileN.json
```

The JSON files contain the following format:

```json
{ "ago": "59 sec ago",  "base_time": 1401243133,  "title": "Untitled",  "type": "None",  "retrieval_time": 1401624105,  "id": "qwNAgvYZ" }
```

I want to rename each `fileX.txt` with the vale of `title` parameter from the respective `fileX.json` file.

For example,

```
rename fileX.txt -> Untitled
```

I can filter that value out as follows;

```bsh
cat fileX.json | awk -F"\"" '{print $10}'
```

But if I encounter an existing filename, it should rename itself with an suffix.

For example, let's say there is an existing `Untitled.txt`. So the new file should be renamed as `Untitled-1.txt`. Next encounter as `Untitled-2.txt` likewise.

Comment: do you want us to do your homework ?

Comment: yes, not my homework though ;) but a project I'm working on.

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to do this in bash?  You really should use something that knows how to parse JSON instead of assuming it'll be, say, `$10`.  You could write a `python` or `perl` script or find a command line tool that understands it rather than a line oriented tool like `awk`

Comment: Eric, its fine if i can use such a parser. appreciate if you could assist me

Comment: [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) is a good json parser for use in shell scripts.  And there are other tools like [jsonpipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpipe) that convert json to line-oriented files suitable for use with awk, sed, grep, etc.  Both are available packaged for most linux distros, as are json-parsing libraries for python, perl, and other lanaguages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple and straight-forward shell script that uses [jsonpipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpipe) to do what you want.  It doesn't use any fancy sh/bash features, and does only the bare minimum sanity checking of filenames.

NOTE: [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) is far more capable than `jsonpipe`, but `jsonpipe` is simpler and easier to use when you don't particularly care (or want to know) about the structure of the json data and only want to extract one or two fields, and/or want to use json data with line-oriented text processing tools like `awk`, `sed`, `grep` etc.

One obvious possible enhancement is to use `printf` with a zero-padded integer field to rename files to fixed-width numbered names, e.g. `Untitled-0001.txt` rather than `Untitled-1.txt`.  I'll leave that for you to do if you want it.

As written, it won't actually rename any file. It will only print the `mv` command that it *would* use.  Edit it to remove the `echo` from before each `mv` command to make it actually rename the files.

```
#! /bin/sh

for f in file*.txt ; do
  b=$(basename "$f" .txt)

  # ignore current .txt file if there's no matching .json file
  if [ -e "$b.json" ] ; then
    # extract the title field.
    title=$(jsonpipe < "$b.json" | 
            awk -F'\t' '$1=="/title" {gsub(/\"/,"",$2) ; print $2}')

    if [ -n "$title" ] ; then
      if [ ! -e "$title.txt" ] ; then
        echo mv -v "$f" "$title.txt"
      else
        # are there any other "$title-*.txt" filenames?
        others=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$title-*.txt")
        if [ -z "$others" ] ; then
          echo mv -v "$f" "$title-1.txt"
        else
          # use version-sort to get highest $title- number used.
          highest=$(printf "%s\n" "$others" | sort -V | tail -n 1)
          hnum=$(printf "%s\n" "$highest" | sed -e 's/^.*-// ; s/\.txt$//')
          hnum=$(( highest_num + 1))
          echo mv -v "$f" "$title-$hnum.txt"
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

Examples of use / Proof that it works:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 132 May 19 23:47 file1.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas   0 May 20 00:04 file1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cas cas 797 May 20 00:04 json-rename.sh

$ cat file1.json 
{"ago": "59 sec ago", "base_time": 1401243133, "title": "Untitled",
 "type": "None", "retrieval_time": 1401624105, "id": "qwNAgvYZ"}

$ ./json-rename.sh 
mv -v file1.txt Untitled.txt

$ touch Untitled.txt
$ ./json-rename.sh 
mv -v file1.txt Untitled-1.txt

$ touch Untitled-1.txt
$ ./json-rename.sh 
mv -v file1.txt Untitled-2.txt

$ touch Untitled-999.txt
$ ./json-rename.sh 
mv -v file1.txt Untitled-1000.txt
```

Comment: works like a charm. to remove the files with "/" i have added the following code segement: `title=${title////_};`

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
for name in file*.txt; do
    json=${name%.txt}.json
    if [ -f "$json" ]; then
        eval "$(
            jq -r --arg name "$name" '[ "mv", "--", $name, .title ] | @sh' "$json"
        )"
    fi
done
```

This loops over all names in the current directory that matches the pattern `file*.txt`.  For each such name, the variable `json` is assigned the corresponding JSON filename by replacing the `.txt` filename suffix with `.json`.

If the generated filename corresponds to an existing file, `jq` is used to parse that JSON file. It builds a shell command for renaming the current file to the string value of the `.title` key in the document.  The shell evaluates the generated command which renames the file.

No check is made for the validity of the JSON file, and name collisions are not handled.

The easiest way to handle name collisions would be to make sure you're using `mv` from GNU coreutils, and then use its `--backup` option.

Modify the `jq` expression into

```bsh
jq -r --arg name "$name" '[ "mv", "-v", "--backup=numbered", "--", $name, .title ] | @sh' "$json"
```

Numbered backups with GNU `mv` means getting filename suffixes like `.~1~`, `.~2~`, etc. added to the end of the backed-up files.  I've also added the `-v` option to GNU `mv` here to get some output about what `mv` is doing, like

```
renamed 'file.txt' -> 'Untitled' (backup: 'Untitled.~2~')
```