# Rename files based on JSON content using jq

Tags: awk, scripting, json, jq

I need to make a shell script that uses jq to rename below mp4 file(s). (could have use jasonpipe but didn't know how to install it on mac)

File Dowloaded:

1. title1-1000221327.mp4
2. title1-1000221327.info.json
3. title1-1000221328.mp4
4. title1-1000221328.info.json

I want to rename file 1&3 by extracting from above respective json file (2&3):

- "series": "ShowName", as ShowName
- "season_number": 1, as "S01"
- "episode_number": 6, as "E006"
- "title": "title1", as title1

also insert space & - between these four variables " "-" "

After rename file should be:

> ShowName - S01E006 - title1.mp4

contents of "title1-1000221327.info.json"

Edit: thanks for the tip:
solved the jq portion sofar

```
jq '"\(.series) - S0\(.season_number)E00\(.episode_number) - \(.title).mp4"'
```

```
{
"description": "Bla Bla Bla",
"episode": "title1",
"episode_number": 6,
"season": "Chapter 1",
"season_number": 1,
"series": "ShowName",
"title": "title1",
"upload_date": "20181006"
}
```

P.S. my question is base on this question:
[Rename files based on JSON content](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283690/350448)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename files based on JSON content](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283690/rename-files-based-on-json-content)

Comment: Since this Questioner does not know how to install jsonpipe, the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283690/rename-files-based-on-json-content cannot apply. An answer should be provided here, possibly linking to the other solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would make it with the find command in Linux to get the filenames out and parse it move the files to the new file name out called from jq.

I hope I can write tomorrow an example for you.

(My English is not the best)

Hope that helps you a little bit out for the start

Daniprog

Edit: use it with this command: find (your path to the files) -type f -name „*.mp4“ -exec mv {} (your new path of the files)(the strings out of the jq array) \;

Comment: This answer lacks the necessary details to be useful to anybody. It is probably better suited as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume we're dealing with files in a single directory (the current directory) and that all JSON files are *correct* in terms of formatting and contents. I'm also assuming that our shell is `bash`.

It looks like you are trying to manually do zero-filling of integers for both the season number (to two digits) and the episode number (to three digits).  We can do that a bit more properly with a `printf` format, but `jq` doesn't support `printf` for formatted output, so what we will create is a shell loop that call `jq` to parse out *a shell command* which, when evaluated, creates a shell variable `newname` with the correct new filename.

```bsh
for name in *.info.json; do
    oldname=${name%.info.json}.mp4

    if [ ! -e "$oldname" ]; then
        printf 'No such file "%s"\n' "$oldname" >&2
        continue
    fi

    unset newname
    eval "$(
        jq -r '[
            "printf", "-v", "newname", "%s - S%.2dE%.3d - %s.mp4",
            .series, .season_number, .episode_number, .title
        ] | @sh' -- "$name"
    )"

    if [ -z "$newname" ] || [ -e "$newname" ]; then
        printf 'Can not rename "%s" to "%s"\n' "$oldname" "$newname" >&2
        continue
    fi

    mv -- "$oldname" "$newname"
done
```

For the given JSON example file, the `jq` command in this loop would create the string

```
'printf' '-v' 'newname' '%s - S%.2dE%.3d - %s.mp4' 'ShowName' 1 6 'title1'
```

The quoting is done by the `@sh` operator, which makes it safe to evaluate in the shell using `eval`.

This shell command would, in `bash`, create the variable `newname` with the contents

```
ShowName - S01E006 - title1.mp4
```

The loop also constructs the expected name of the file that needs to be renamed.  If that name does not exist, a diagnostic message is printed and the loop simply skips to the next name.

Before actually renaming the file, a rudimentary sanity check on the new name is performed to make sure it's actually set to something and that the new name isn't already taken by some other file.